# Setting Default TIMESTAMP in SQL Column

Tags: sql, timestamp, default-value

I am creating a Table and I have a column that is `TIMESTAMP`.

I want to set a default value to it. How can I do that ?

For Example:

I have a `USER_LAST_SEEN` table, and I have two columns:

1) `username`
2) `logout date`

and I want to be able to tell if a user has never been logged out yet, by setting a default timestamp I can then look for. How do I do that ?

```
CREATE TABLE LAST_SEEN_TABLE (USERNAME STRING, LOGOUT_DATE TIMESTAMP [What am I missing here?])
```

Edit: Saving NULL is not a good solution, because of the scenario that a user already exists when I create the table. Showing "Never logged in", which is shown when a user DOES have `NULL`, is wrong in this case. I need a way to have ANOTHER indication that user DID log in before in order to show "N/A"

Comment: Why don't just leave the `logout` date as NULL if user never logs out ?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: are you using sql server or what?

Comment: Just add default constraint as current_timestamp to your column .

Comment: @rcs the "NULL" is in fact used for something else in this context. That's why I don't use it and I'm looking for another solution

Comment: @Ofri . . . I think you are overloading the values in a single column and should have explicit tags instead of playing with default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot use `NULL`, you can use a specific date, for example '1900-01-01'

```
CREATE TABLE LAST_SEEN_TABLE 
(
    USERNAME varchar(100), 
    LOGOUT_DATE TIMESTAMP default '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want to know how to do !